# Good Java EE testing framework?

Tags: java, testing, frameworks, jakarta-ee

I have googled a lot and there are several options,

1. [Arquillian](http://jboss.org/arquillian)
2. [JUnitEE](http://www.junitee.org/index.html)
3. [Cactus](http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/)

Does anyone have experience with one of these (or other frameworks)? Do they depend on JUnit only or does TestNG work as well? Please give me your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't had direct experience with any of them, but after some reading, it seems that Arquillian is the newest one, it has an experienced company backing it, and it has a lot of hype surrounding it. Criteria that I have enumerated don't necessarily say Arquillian is quality wise the best out there, since that would be a pretty subjective argument. I'd say it's worth checking out.

JUnitEE's last release was about 6 years ago, and from what I've read, Cactus is a bit complicated and "heavyweight". If I were to use one of Java EE unit testing frameworks you've listed, I'd try Arquillian first.

Comment: Thanks. I too am inclined to Arquillian which is backed by JBoss community.